# Strange behavior with Thread and Fiber

Tags: ruby, multithreading, fibers

This code:

```
Fiber.new do 
  Thread.current['a'] = 5

  p Thread.current.object_id
  p Thread.current['a']

  Fiber.new do 
    p Thread.current.object_id
    p Thread.current['a']
  end.resume

  p Thread.current.object_id
  p Thread.current['a']
end.resume
```

shows the following results:

```
3442840
5

3442840
nil

3442840
5
```

Why does `current['a']` return `nil` in nested fiber? How can it be explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Thread#[]` and `Thread#[]=` are **not thread-local but fiber-local**. This
>   confusion did not exist in Ruby 1.8 because fibers were only available
>   since Ruby 1.9. Ruby 1.9 chooses that the methods behaves fiber-local
>   to save following idiom for dynamic scope.

— [Thread class doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html#method-i-5B-5D)